# Syntax error in R.java in android

Tags: java, android

I get the following syntax error in R.java

```
 public static final int abs__shareactionprovider_share_with_application=0x7f0a0007;
    /**  Replace placeholder ID with your tracking ID 
     */
    public static final int ga_trackingId=0x7f0a000d;
    public static final int Î¤Î§Î¤_BYTECODE=0x7f0a0065;
    public static final int Î¤Î§Î¤_EMPTY=0x7f0a0064;
    public static final int Î¤Î§Î¤_EVERY_30_DAYS=0x7f0a0048;
    public static final int Î¤Î§Î¤_EVERY_7_DAYS=0x7f0a0047;
    public static final int Î¤Î§Î¤_EVERY_90_DAYS=0x7f0a0049;
    public static final int Î¤Î§Î¤_EVERY_DAY=0x7f0a0046;
}
```

I tried to delete these lines but nothing happens can you please help me solve this

Comment: you can't modify R file, find where you use this value and remove or change from that. check layout file and menu file\

Comment: delete the gen folder, and then clean and build your project. additionally test if there are issues in your xml files.

Comment: Well, that's only a partial of the code, doesn't state the error, and is part of something "compiled" from your code... nothing of which leads to the error unless as shayan pointed out might be the case you are editing the file directly.

Comment: there might be errors in your resources folder so just check it and clean your project..

Comment: see error list in Problems tab.

Comment: I have a bunch of files in res folder what could usually be causing this strings file or layouts?

Comment: why are you getting Î¤Î§Î¤ this in your R.java names

Comment: @shayanpourvatan he can but he shouldn't

Comment: If you are using Android Studio just clean your project and try to rebuild it

Comment: @ABFORCE if he changed value after cleaned or build all thing back. am i right?

Comment: @shayanpourvatan If your clean and then build your project, the `R.java` file will be recreated

Answer (score 3):

Error in R file is usually caused by errors in your res directory. Layouts, drawables, values, any of these folders might be the culprit. The first thing you need to do is check all your layout files for errors. Then project clean and restarting ide would be ideal. Also you cannot modify R file because it will be regenerated automatically after any alteration.

**UPDATE**
Check your xml files for references to _BYTECODE and all the fields in R.java that have non english unicode like characters. Resolve the errors in those xml files. Rebuild your project. Project clean or save and close ide.

Comment: what are reasons this errors occurs I mean what should I look for while checking res folder?

Comment: as i mentioned in my answer the entire res folder themes can give you error in styles.xml file string tag in values without name would cause R file to make a static int id with no name (i got this error once) drawable png with - character is also invalid. Check your lint and console for errors

Comment: it says Syntax error on token "Invalid Character", , expected

Comment: i have many like <string name="TXT_CAT_BYTECODE">ByteCode</string>     what should i do  about them?

Comment: i also had res/menu/values-el i deleted that aslo as they were non english